# Node.js - PUT with 'request' module

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-put

I am using the request module in Node.js to do a put request.  My code looks like this

```
var request = require('request');
var data = {foo: "bar", woo: "car"};

request({
   method: 'PUT',
   uri: myURL,
   multipart: [{
       'content-type':'application/json',
       body: JSON.stringify(data) 
   }]
}, function(error, request, body){
   console.log(body);
});
```

When I run this I get an error:

"Unsupported content with type: application/json"

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just try it like this:

`request({ url: url, method: 'PUT', json: {foo: "bar", woo: "car"}}, callback)`

Comment: And where would I include headers?

Comment: headers is just a nested JSON in the options JSON.

Comment: what about a put request with a file upload?